# ssh: can still use password after setting the key

Tags: ssh, authentication

I followed [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) tutorial to set up SSH. Now it prompts for the passphrase, but when I type nothing and hit return, it asks for the password and I can use it to login. How can I prevent that?

My `sshd_config` is as follows:

```
Port 22
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel VERBOSE

LoginGraceTime 20
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no

PermitEmptyPasswords no

ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

PasswordAuthentication no

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

UsePAM yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've turned off `PasswordAuthentication` (i.e. `sshd`'s built-in password authentication), but turned on `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` (i.e. authentication through PAM, which by default means password authentication). If you only want key-based authentication, turn off `ChallengeResponseAuthentication`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you restart the ssh daemon?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the owner and permission of the .ssh directory?

Its directory and the files inside should be own by the login id. The directory should be with permission 700 (only the login user allow to access) and the files should be 600.

Comment: Ownership and permissions of .ssh are irrelevant in terms of editing sshd_config to disallow password use.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you assigned a passphrase to your private key.  This is what you get prompted for on your connection attempt.  You'll need to remove that, so the private key is no longer encrypted.  You can recreate the key while setting a blank password (and also entering it into the allowed_hosts file).  Alternately, set a blank passphrase from the current key, by using `ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]`


--Christopher Karel

Comment: Gregory told us that it asks first for key passphrase, then next for ssh (pam) password. moreover protecting a private key with a passphrase is a good thing.